# ActivePDF Webgrabber, ignore &t and &d placeholders

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webgrabber

Is there a way to globally disable the ampersand placeholders used by ActivePDF Webgrabber?  I am finding that any instances of `&t` and `&d` are being replaced with dates and times and I do not want that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing &t & &d with & amp;t and & amp;d?  [Remove the (space) inserted between & and amp;]

Those replacements are only supposed to happen in the headers and footers though.